# How to make synapse control Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, synapse

Synapse can control banshee just fine. Commands such as "Pause", "Next", "Play" work fine; however, the same isn't true for Rhythmbox. Synapse falsely believes that Rhythmbox is not installed and thus I can't enable the controls. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: did you find any solution to this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: No I didn't. I even posted a question on Synapse's launchpad page and didn't get any answers.